# Visual bug with chat layout

Tags: bug, design, chat

The current layout for the chat room needs some fix to avoid partially hiding the [enable desktop notification](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development#) link.

[image: Chat room screenshot]

Comment: What browser (etc) are you using? The display issue above only occurs for me when resizing the window vertically (when all the star column text can be partially obscured by the black bar). Once live resize stops, the text reflows fine.

Comment: Your question about a chat FAQ is better asked separately.

Comment: Ok about FAQ in new question. About my browser, it's on Chrome, Firefox and IExplorer. Maybe it's due to my screen resolution (1366x768), but it works well in all chat rooms I tried except gamedev.